# How do I save the image information as .bil using the Vimba API for python for the allied vision cameras?

Tags: python, alliedvision, vimba-sdk

I have trained a model to detect the object's position using the .bil file(for my camera, 168 bands for each pixel) as the input captured directly from the camera's default software. How do I gather the same on python for real-time object detection?

I tried searching on the web but got no clue and am not sure if the API provides such functionality. If there is some alternate method to achieve the same, please guide.